# How to get last build date of a job from Jenkins in Java

Tags: java, json, jenkins, build

I have a job scheduled in Jenkins and it has lets say 370 total builds. I can see the date right next to build number in the build history part of the page but when I try to access the JSON content of that page like `http:localhost:8080/job/job_name/api/json` I am not getting that date for the latest build in that JSON content.

Any other way to access the date when the last build happended?

I have to use the same in Java so might be there is any API to access the Jenkins?

Answer (score 11):

As [Harshavardhan Konakanchi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38349209/1744774) mentioned in his answer there's the `/lastBuild/` URL path. You can get exactly the information you want by using:

```
<JENKINS_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastBuild/api/json?tree=timestamp
```

Example output:

```
{"timestamp":1467898403630}
```

See `<JENKINS_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastBuild/api/` for a description of the API.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this could solve you out or not, but here is my workaround

Access url `/job/<job_name>/lastBuild/api/json` retrieve `timestamp`

Convert epoch time to required date-time format